# R: How to remove rows in a dataframe when a column contains a value similar to that in a character vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, matching

I have a column in a dataframe that lists various medications. However, instances of the same medication may be spelled slightly differently, or have another word tacked on (e.g., "Ibuprofen", "ibuprofen 200mg", "Ibuprofen Pill"). I want to find each instance in the column of my dataframe that has a similar value to that I have entered in my character vector. So, for the example above, if my character vector has "Ibuprofen", I want to remove any row where the corresponding value in that column has "ibuprofen pill" or "ibuprofen 200 mg" ect.

I have already tried filtering with dplyr , but it only removes complete matches. I made sure that the column of which I am looking for similar matches is also of class "character."

```r
list_of_meds <- c("Ibuprofen", "Advil", "Tylenol")
df$meds <- as.character(df$meds)
df <- df %>%
  filter(!meds %in% list_of_meds)
```

```
    ID   meds
    2    ibuprofen
    3    Ibuprofen Pill
    4    ibuprofen 200 mg
    5    iBuprofen/ inhaler
    6    melatonin/ ibuprofen/ aspirin 500 mg
```

This method only seems to remove exact matches to the values in my vector. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like regular expression is needed. Please provide a reproducible example of your data frame.

Comment: @www example has been added!

Comment: @m4148  Do you want all of those removed, including the last one?

Comment: @G5W yes, any instance of one of the medications in my list, even if there are others listed!

Answer (score 1):

I am enhancing your example data to include a few things that *should not* be removed.

```
df = read.table(text="ID   meds
    2    ibuprofen
    3    'Ibuprofen Pill'
    4    'ibuprofen 200 mg'
    5    'iBuprofen/ inhaler'
    6    'melatonin/ ibuprofen/ aspirin 500 mg'
    7    melatonin
    8    'pure water'",
stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)

df[-grep(paste(list_of_meds, collapse="|"), df$meds, ignore.case=T),]
      meds
6  7  melatonin
7  8 pure water
```

This just makes a regular expression to find any med list that contains one of your listed medicines as a substring. It then finds those rows and removes them.